# DUPLICATE_VALUE in upsert call - Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, upsert

I'm trying to do a bulk upsert via REST API in Salesforce, but I'm getting the following error:

```
<results xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
    <result>
        <errors>
            <message>duplicate value found: ID_Externo__c duplica o valor no registro com ID: 0014B00000RKZkR
</message>
            <statusCode>DUPLICATE_VALUE</statusCode>
        </errors>
        <success>false</success>
        <created>true</created>
    </result>
    <result>
        <errors>
            <message>duplicate value found: ID_Externo__c duplica o valor no registro com ID: 0014B00000RKZkP
</message>
            <statusCode>DUPLICATE_VALUE</statusCode>
        </errors>
        <success>false</success>
        <created>true</created>
    </result>
    <result>
        <errors>
            <message>duplicate value found: ID_Externo__c duplica o valor no registro com ID: 0014B00000RKZkS
</message>
            <statusCode>DUPLICATE_VALUE</statusCode>
        </errors>
        <success>false</success>
        <created>true</created>
    </result>
    <result>
        <errors>
            <fields>ID_Externo__c</fields>
            <message>Duplicate external id specified: 062.203.686-6501237000000RgoCAAS
</message>
            <statusCode>DUPLICATE_VALUE</statusCode>
        </errors>
        <success>false</success>
        <created>false</created>
    </result>
    <result>
        <errors>
            <message>duplicate value found: ID_Externo__c duplica o valor no registro com ID: 0014B00000RKZkT
</message>
            <statusCode>DUPLICATE_VALUE</statusCode>
        </errors>
        <success>false</success>
        <created>true</created>
    </result>
    <result>
        <errors>
            <message>duplicate value found: ID_Externo__c duplica o valor no registro com ID: 0014B00000RKZkU
</message>
            <statusCode>DUPLICATE_VALUE</statusCode>
        </errors>
        <success>false</success>
        <created>true</created>
    </result>
    <result>
        <errors>
            <fields>ID_Externo__c</fields>
            <message>Duplicate external id specified: 062.203.686-6501237000000RgoCAAS
</message>
            <statusCode>DUPLICATE_VALUE</statusCode>
        </errors>
        <success>false</success>
        <created>false</created>
    </result>
    <result>
        <errors>
            <message>duplicate value found: ID_Externo__c duplica o valor no registro com ID: 0014B00000RKZkV
</message>
            <statusCode>DUPLICATE_VALUE</statusCode>
        </errors>
        <success>false</success>
        <created>true</created>
    </result>
    <result>
        <errors>
            <message>duplicate value found: ID_Externo__c duplica o valor no registro com ID: 0014B00000RKZkW
</message>
            <statusCode>DUPLICATE_VALUE</statusCode>
        </errors>
        <success>false</success>
        <created>true</created>
    </result>
    <result>
        <errors>
            <message>duplicate value found: ID_Externo__c duplica o valor no registro com ID: 0014B00000RKZkX
</message>
            <statusCode>DUPLICATE_VALUE</statusCode>
        </errors>
        <success>false</success>
        <created>true</created>
    </result>
</results>
```

In my request, I'm not sending duplicate values (except one that I create for test, and getting the correct error - Duplicate external id specified).

Here is my request:

```
<sObjects xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <sObject>
        <CPF_CNPJ__c>672.334.062-00</CPF_CNPJ__c>
        <Name>672.334.062-00</Name>
        <RecordType>
            <sObject>
                <Name>Cliente Varejo</Name>
            </sObject>
        </RecordType>
        <Clear__c>true</Clear__c>
        <ID_Externo__c>672.334.062-0001237000000RgoCAAS</ID_Externo__c>
    </sObject>
    <sObject>
        <CPF_CNPJ__c>035.621.729-90</CPF_CNPJ__c>
        <Name>035.621.729-90</Name>
        <RecordType>
            <sObject>
                <Name>Cliente Varejo</Name>
            </sObject>
        </RecordType>
        <Clear__c>true</Clear__c>
        <ID_Externo__c>035.621.729-9001237000000RgoCAAS</ID_Externo__c>
    </sObject>
    <sObject>
        <CPF_CNPJ__c>303.292.018-32</CPF_CNPJ__c>
        <Name>303.292.018-32</Name>
        <RecordType>
            <sObject>
                <Name>Cliente Varejo</Name>
            </sObject>
        </RecordType>
        <Clear__c>true</Clear__c>
        <ID_Externo__c>303.292.018-3201237000000RgoCAAS</ID_Externo__c>
    </sObject>
    <sObject>
        <CPF_CNPJ__c>062.203.686-65</CPF_CNPJ__c>
        <Name>062.203.686-65</Name>
        <RecordType>
            <sObject>
                <Name>Cliente Varejo</Name>
            </sObject>
        </RecordType>
        <Clear__c>true</Clear__c>
        <ID_Externo__c>062.203.686-6501237000000RgoCAAS</ID_Externo__c>
    </sObject>
    <sObject>
        <CPF_CNPJ__c>054.454.224-02</CPF_CNPJ__c>
        <Name>054.454.224-02</Name>
        <RecordType>
            <sObject>
                <Name>Cliente Varejo</Name>
            </sObject>
        </RecordType>
        <Clear__c>true</Clear__c>
        <ID_Externo__c>054.454.224-0201237000000RgoCAAS</ID_Externo__c>
    </sObject>
    <sObject>
        <CPF_CNPJ__c>845.374.266-91</CPF_CNPJ__c>
        <Name>845.374.266-91</Name>
        <RecordType>
            <sObject>
                <Name>Cliente Varejo</Name>
            </sObject>
        </RecordType>
        <Clear__c>true</Clear__c>
        <ID_Externo__c>845.374.266-9101237000000RgoCAAS</ID_Externo__c>
    </sObject>
    <sObject>
        <CPF_CNPJ__c>062.203.686-65</CPF_CNPJ__c>
        <Name>062.203.686-65</Name>
        <RecordType>
            <sObject>
                <Name>Cliente Varejo</Name>
            </sObject>
        </RecordType>
        <Clear__c>true</Clear__c>
        <ID_Externo__c>062.203.686-6501237000000RgoCAAS</ID_Externo__c>
    </sObject>
    <sObject>
        <CPF_CNPJ__c>041.235.286-94</CPF_CNPJ__c>
        <Name>041.235.286-94</Name>
        <RecordType>
            <sObject>
                <Name>Cliente Varejo</Name>
            </sObject>
        </RecordType>
        <Clear__c>true</Clear__c>
        <ID_Externo__c>041.235.286-9401237000000RgoCAAS</ID_Externo__c>
    </sObject>
    <sObject>
        <CPF_CNPJ__c>258.419.948-32</CPF_CNPJ__c>
        <Name>258.419.948-32</Name>
        <RecordType>
            <sObject>
                <Name>Cliente Varejo</Name>
            </sObject>
        </RecordType>
        <Clear__c>true</Clear__c>
        <ID_Externo__c>258.419.948-3201237000000RgoCAAS</ID_Externo__c>
    </sObject>
    <sObject>
        <CPF_CNPJ__c>126.912.867-11</CPF_CNPJ__c>
        <Name>126.912.867-11</Name>
        <RecordType>
            <sObject>
                <Name>Cliente Varejo</Name>
            </sObject>
        </RecordType>
        <Clear__c>true</Clear__c>
        <ID_Externo__c>126.912.867-1101237000000RgoCAAS</ID_Externo__c>
    </sObject>
</sObjects>
```

The field "ID_Externo__c" is Exclusive, Case Sensitive and External Id.
If I disable the exclusive tag, the upsert call duplicates the registry; and, if I try to make the field exclusive again, obviously, Salesforce give me an error of duplicate external id found.

Thanks

Comment: What debugging have you done to try and solve the issue? Is all the code posted necessary to show the error? If not reduce the code so just the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

You have ID_Externo_c : 062.203.686-6501237000000RgoCAAS referenced twice: 4th and 7th records.

Comment: Yes! But this one is OK, with the error:
Duplicate external id specified

But I'm getting errors for all of the records